# Need to identify a European uniform from around 1900

Tags: world-war-one, identification, uniform

[image: Male in blue? uniform in or around 1900. Collar insignia and dagger should help with ID]

This is my great grandfather...from somewhere in eastern Europe...family from Istria.

Comment: It the ghost image present in the original, or caused by glare when you took  this shot?  If the latter, can you take a better shot?

Answer (score 2):

[In this photograph](https://www.flickriver.com/photos/157013622@N05/39821158423/), an individual identified as an Austro-Hungarian soldier seems to be wearing a similar uniform, complete with the three dots on the gorget (collar), epaulets, belt, and bayonet. Your image is too dark to make out the pocket details. Since Istria was part of the Austro-Hungarian empire until 1918 someone from that region serving in the A-H military would not be surprising.

Comment: Please expand your answer to a point where it is still valid should the link go dead. Spell out what "this" and "the ID" actually are.